# Issues with using a variable from another class

Tags: java, android, button, ip, ping

I am working on an android app that will ping an IP address after clicking on a button.

I have two classes. An activity for the Button, and a ping class. On button click, I set an IP variable to "8.8.8.8", then pass it to a pingIP method in my ping class. My app crashes after button press. After using the debugger, I can see that my IP variable remains "8.8.8.8" until I get into the ping class, where the variable is set to null.

```
       ///This is my onClick action for the button presspublic void onClick(View v)  @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            IP = "8.8.8.8";

            pingout = new ping(); ///Creating new ping instance
            pingout.pingIP(IP); //passing the pingIP method the IP variable
          }
```

This is my ping class:

```
    public class ping  {

        public void pingIP (String ip) { <- this value is null after the 
                                         function is called in the button class.
            InetAddress adr = null;
            try {

                adr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                System.out.println("Reachable Host: " + " " + ip + " " + adr.isReachable(3000));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            boolean status = false;

            try {
                status = adr.isReachable(3000);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Reachable Host:" + " " + ip + " " + status);
     }

  }
```

The ping class is part of my project package. Should I declare the class as an extension of the class where the button resides?

Comment: Post the error that you are getting

Comment: Okay, so I found the stack trace in the Android Monitor. It looks like I was missing a brace at the end of one of my Try Catch blocks. This is weird, because usually AS goes nuts with the red squiggly lines if I miss something like that, yet I had no indication of that typo. Anyway, it appears fixed for now.